# time of day based div refresh

Tags: javascript, html, refresh

Hey, how do you refresh a div on a certain hour?
So the timed based greeting ticks over automatically.
the code I have at the moment is this:

```
<div id = "greet" ><script>
var Digital=new Date()
var hours=Digital.getHours()
if (hours < 12)
document.write('Good morning.')
else if (hours >= 12 && hours < 18) 
// (code in here?) refresh the div at 12:00 pm
document.write('Good afternoon.')
else if (hours >= 18 && hours <= 24)
// (code in here?) refresh div at 6:00 pm
document.write('Good evening.')
</script></div>
```

any tips would be great.
cheers.

Comment: you can use a setTimeOut , ticking at every minute or second to check the current time and update greetings accordingly

Answer (score 0):

are you need like this

```js
var datas="";
var Digital=new Date()
var hours=Digital.getHours()
if (hours < 12){
datas = 12 ? "is a below 12am" : "";
document.write('Good morning.')
}
else if (hours >= 12 && hours < 18) {
   datas = 12 ? "is a 12am" : "";
document.write('Good afternoon.')}
else if (hours >= 18 && hours <= 24){
  datas = 18 ? "is a 6pm" : "";
document.write('Good evening.')
}
document.getElementById('greet').innerHTML=datas;
```

```html
<div id = "greet" ></div>
```